# The process to reduce modular congruences?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

For example. given $15x\equiv 10\ (mod \ 16)$, what method would someone use to reduce this to $x \equiv 6\ (mod \ 16)$?

Comment: Take the negative of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

$15 = 3\cdot 5$.  So find the multiplicative inverse of $3$ which is $11$ and of $5$ which is $13$.  Then multiply $10 \cdot 11 = 110$.  Modulo $16$ that's $110 - 6 \cdot 16 = 14$.  Then $14  \cdot 13 = 140 + 42$.  Modulo $16$ that's $12 + 10 = 22 = 6 \pmod{16}$.

---

But that takes a while.

So notice that $15 = 16 - 1 = -1 \pmod {16}$ and that $-10 = 16 - 6$.  So you multiply both sides by $-1$.

Comment: I am kind of confused how taking the negative leads anywhere. You now have $-15x \equiv -10(mod 16)$ but I don't see how that changes anything exactly

Comment: @user3491700 $-y = 16 - y \pmod {16}$.  Use that to transform the 15 and the 10.